# Using xte in linux script

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard, command

I have a question about xte and how it works in a linux ubuntu script.

My script opens a program (./program_to_open) and a file concurrently (~path/to/file.txt).  The line is:

```
./program_to_open ~/path/to/file.txt
```

I would like to use the keyboard command "Control+S" to save this file.  If I understand xte correctly, and I probably don't, I'd use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Desktop/user/folder...
./file_to_open ~/path/to/file.txt
sleep 3
xte 'key Control_S'
```

...or...

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Desktop/user/folder...    
./file_to_open ~/path/to/file.txt
sleep 3
xte 'keydown Control_S'
sleep 1
xte 'keyup Control_S'
```

Is this the way it's supposed to work or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the only way to hold down multiple keys at the same with `xte` is using several `keydown` commands. The following worked for me:

```
xte 'sleep 3' 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown s' 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup s'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not keyup the control until you have keyup the 's'.  But when you swap the last two actions, you put the s actiosn together, so they als can be merged into one action.

```
xte 'sleep 3' 'keydown Control_L' 'key s' 'keyup Control_L'
```

Though for this type of thing I prefer to use xdotool

```
xdotool keydown Control key s keyup control
```

Xdotool has the advantage of finding the windows you want to control, and even moving the mouse around relative to the window. This can make using "visgrep" for mouse clicking 'images' relative to the window a lot easier.